# Can't connect to RDS DB after moving it from one VPC to another (timeout error) [AWS RDS & VPC]

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I moved my db into a new VPC, where my Lambda function sits, so that I could interact with the database through my fullstack app. While I'm now able to access the data over the internet (through the web app), I'm not able to access the rds instance from my pgAdmin 4 console or code on my local machine - something I could do before. The weird part is that the NAT Gateway, Internet Gateway & route tables are all configured but it's still not working.

I have **already done** the following:

1. Made the DB publically accessible
2. Updated Security Groups to add the IP Address where I'm accessing the DB instance from
3. Added the necessary Gateways
4. Added both my public subnets (for internet access) & private subnets (for lambda) to the subnet group

but still get a timeout error.

Comment: Did you check if the subnet you moved your RDS instance to have an ACL associated?

Comment: The network ACLs & their associated inbound & outbound rules are configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the RDS instance back to the original VPC, added data to it through local code and moved it back to the new VPC (for the full stack app). & now the database is accessible through local codebase and full stack app. Doesn't make sense but works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).